# Will spawned processes inside docker container utilize all cpu cores on container host by default?

Tags: docker

I have been trying to find out whats the default behavior of docker with regards to usage of host cpu cores? Does anyone know if it will utilize multiple cpu cores for each process inside the container, or if it will run all processes on just one cpu core on the host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to read about the [CPU Sharing and Constraint Docs](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#cpu-share-constraint) - basically, yes, if you go with the default a container will use up to 100% of the CPU, but you can control this with a constraint on the CPU usage with `--cpu-period` and `--cpu-quota` For more information on how cpu period and quota work, see the [kernel docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/sched-bwc.txt)